# After applying saveAsCSVFile action in spark nothing happens while submitting job in yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am submitting a spark job(via jar) in yarn client;

```
./spark-submit --class main.MainClass --master yarn-client  --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2 job.jar <other_args>
```

Now I have the following code in my jar;

```
dataset.write().mode("overwrite").csv(/the/file/path/)
```

I am getting log like;

```
17/03/22 02:44:26 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (csv at SaveAsCSVFileAction.java:53) finished in 1.948 s
17/03/22 02:44:26 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: csv at SaveAsCSVFileAction.java:53, took 2.044570 s
```

But I am not getting my result in **/the/file/path/**

**/the/file/path/** is absolute path of computer, like /home/somename/Desktop/resultDump

Can you please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I finally understand that local file path is not accessible from inside yarn cluster. So the change **hdfs://host:port/path** worked well.